# Distributed Z3 and best hardware for each node

Tags: hardware, z3, distributed-computing, smt

I'm thinking on starting a cluster of servers which will be running exclusively Z3 to solve SMT formulas.

Is there any way to clusterize several servers to join computational power and solve SMT formulas in a distributed fashion? 
What are the recommendation characteristics of an system that will be running Z3 to be as fast as possible (regarding to hardware)?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAT/SMT solvers are usually very heavy on memory due to low cache hits.  Therefore you can't run many processes on a CPU, otherwise they soon start degrading the performance of each other  (i.e., running one process per core is not a good idea if you want to benchmark).

I can't give any specific recomendation, but I would choose CPUs that have fewer cores (say 4) and high memory bandwidth. These days CPUs have a fixed TDP and the fewer the CPUs the more powerful each one is -- and less contention for the memory.

Also you want to stick with little-endian architectures. At the moment, Z3 doesn't play well with big-endian archs (such as many ARMs, MIPS, SPARCs, etc). Moreover, for what I've seen, 64 bits usually helps.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if I can use Z3 in a distributed fashion? thank you

Comment: you can't.  There's a parallel mode (with OpenMP), though, but the speedups can between anywhere between < 1 to a few %, depending on the type of problems you want to solve.  Not worth it if you have enough problems to keep your machines busy.